# Using clearbox with a codeigniter site

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I'm trying to use [clearbox](http://www.clearbox.hu/index_en.html) with a codeigniter site. I'm not able to get it to work and I have a feeling it has to do with this line which is located in clearbox.js. I'm not sure if it has to be relative to my view file or what.

```
var CB_ScriptDir='clearbox'; // RELATIVE to your html file!
```

Anyone ever used this plugin before?

Comment: What error you get? Have you tried to use firebug in Firefox to see if it have some url broken (images, css...)?

Comment: It takes you to the url of that image rather than putting it in a clearbox.

Comment: It sounds like javascript error and not Codeigniter. Check with firefox for errors (error console) when you load the page...

Comment: It's not a js error. You don't even have to call anything in js. It's supposed to be done automatically in the plugin assuming you have the var CB_ScriptDir set correctly (I think).

Comment: I'm trying to say that if your clearbox.js was loaded correctly, at least your browser won't go to the url of the image. You put the "rel=clearbox" right? The tip of the firebug still good...

Comment: There is no js error. I've checked that. Yes i've put rel="clearbox"

Comment: @Catfish do you have any demo link that we can see?

Comment: I don't have anything online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be relative to your index.html page. 
When you download the clearbox zip file from the developers page, you get a containing folder called "clearbox" which has both clearbox.js and the actual folder clearbox inside it. If you have your zip containing folder at the level of your index.html page, you would set parameters as follows:

```
var CB_ScriptDir='clearbox/clearbox'; // RELATIVE to your html file!
```

If you take both clearbox.js and the folder clearbox out of the containing clearbox folder, your setting would be:

```
var CB_ScriptDir='clearbox'; // RELATIVE to your html file!
```

The confusion is with the zip extracting clearbox inside a folder named clearbox!

Answer (score 0):

I think that if your website stracture is like

- index.html
- js (directory)
- - clearbox.js
- - - clearbox (directory)

Than you should set CB_ScriptDir like this:

```
var CB_ScriptDir='js/clearbox';
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a /js dir in the top directory where your index.php resides. Put clearbox.js and folder /clearbox.

```
var CB_ScriptDir='../../../js/clearbox';
```